# Add Multiplie values in list for the same key using python

Tags: python, json

Please check the below code and my output. I have run my code i got the below output but i want Expected Result.

`list_data = ['ABCD:SATARA', 'XYZ:MUMBAI', 'PQR:43566', 'LMN:455667', 'XYZ:PUNE']`

Expected Result is :-

```
{
  "ABCD": "SATARA",
  "XYZ": ["MUMBAI", "PUNE"]
  "PQR": "43566",
  "LMN": "455667"
}
```

My Code :-

```
list_data = ['ABCD:SATARA', 'XYZ:MUMBAI', 'PQR:43566', 'LMN:455667', 'XYZ:PUNE']

    for each_split_data in list_data:
        split_by_colon = each_split_data.split(":")
        if split_by_colon[0] is not '':
            if split_by_colon[0] in splittded_data_dict:
                # append the new number to the existing array at this slot
                splittded_data_dict[split_by_colon[0]].append(split_by_colon[1])
            else:
                # create a new array in this slot
                splittded_data_dict[split_by_colon[0]] = [split_by_colon[1]]

    print(json.dumps(splittded_data_dict, indent=2), "\n")
```

My OUTPUT :-

```
{
  "ABCD": [
    "SATARA"
  ],
    "REF": [
    "MUMBAI.",
    "PUNE"
  ],
  "PQR": [
    "43566"
  ],
  "LMN": [
    "455667"
  ]
}
```

How can i solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isinstance` function to check if a key has been transformed into a list:

```
d = {}
for i in list_data:
    k, v = i.split(':', 1)
    if k in d:
        if not isinstance(d[k], list):
            d[k] = [d[k]]
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = v
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'ABCD': 'SATARA', 'XYZ': ['MUMBAI', 'PUNE'], 'PQR': '43566', 'LMN': '455667'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do in my opinion would be to use a [`defaultdict` from the `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Have a look:

```
from collections import defaultdict


list_data = ['ABCD:SATARA', 'XYZ:MUMBAI', 'PQR:43566', 'LMN:455667', 'XYZ:PUNE']

res = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_data:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    res[key].append(value)
```

which results in:

```
print(res)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ABCD': ['SATARA'], 'XYZ': ['MUMBAI', 'PUNE'], 'PQR': ['43566'], 'LMN': ['455667']})
```

or cast it to dict for a more familiar output:

```
res = dict(res)
print(res)
# {'ABCD': ['SATARA'], 'XYZ': ['MUMBAI', 'PUNE'], 'PQR': ['43566'], 'LMN': ['455667']}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand by the description of your problem statement, you want `splittded_data_dict` to be a dictionary where each value is a list
For this purpose try using `defaultdict().` Please see the example below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

splittded_data_dict = defaultdict(list)
splittded_data_dict['existing key'].append('New value')

print(splittded_data_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's append all possible key values from the string items in the `list_data`. Get the list of unique items. Now loop through the `list_data` and check if the first item of the ":" split string matched with the list `a` and if matches append to a temporary list and at last assign that temporary list as the value to the key of the item in the list `a`.

**Here is oneliner using dict comprehension and list comprehension** simultaneously :

```
   c = {i : [j.split(":")[1] for j in list_data if j.split(":")[0] == i ][0] if len([j.split(":")[1] for j in list_data if j.split(":")[0] == i ])==1 else [j.split(":")[1] for j in list_data if j.split(":")[0] == i ] for i in list(set([i.split(":")[0] for i in list_data]))}
```

Output should be :

```
# c = {'LMN': '455667', 'ABCD': 'SATARA', 'PQR': '43566', 'XYZ': ['MUMBAI', 'PUNE']}
```

Here is the long and detailed version of the code :

```
list_data = ['ABCD:SATARA', 'XYZ:MUMBAI', 'PQR:43566', 'LMN:455667', 'XYZ:PUNE']
a = []
for i in list_data:
    a.append(i.split(":")[0])
a = list(set(a))
b = {}
for i in a:
    temp = []
    for j in list_data:
        if j.split(":")[0] == i:
            temp.append(j.split(":")[1])
    if len(temp) > 1:
        b[i] = temp
    else:
        b[i] = temp[0]
```